# Django UnicodeDecodeError in model object

Tags: django, encoding

this is another UnicodeDecodeError I'm dealing with in django. I can't find the way to solve it.

I'm trying to create an object:

```
nivel_obj = Nivel.objects.filter(id=nivel_id)
nueva_matricula = Matricula(nivel=nivel_obj, ano_lectivo=ano_lectivo, alumno=a)
nueva_matricula.save()
```

The "Matricula" object has a "nivel_obj" that is a Foreign Key. The "nivel_obj" has a name that is a string that could not be encoded/decoded.

How can I solve this?

These are the models:

```
class Nivel(models.Model):
    """
    Ej - "Octavo de Basica, 6to Curso"
    """
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "niveles"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.nombre)


class Matricula(models.Model):
    ano_lectivo = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999)])
    alumno = models.ForeignKey(Alumno)
    nivel = models.ForeignKey(Nivel, null=True) <----
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=(("A", "Activo"), ("I", "Inactivo")))

    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        if Matricula.objects.filter(alumno=self.alumno, nivel=self.nivel, ano_lectivo=self.ano_lectivo).exists():
            error = u'Ya existe una matrícula igual, por favor revisa el año, el nivel y el alumno'
            raise ValidationError({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: error})
        else:
            pass

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "matrículas"
        verbose_name = "matrícula"

        ordering = ("alumno",)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Matricula %s %s" % (self.alumno, self.ano_lectivo)
```

The exact error comes from a "Nivel" object that has a name like this "Octavo de Básica", I can't work with it without having a UnicodeDecodeError.

This is the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /sisacademico/matricular_grupo/

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

...

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: de B��sica
```

**EDIT: Found the Error**

OK I found my error, I'm not going to delete the question cause the error (UnicodeDecodeError) django was giving me is completely misleading. The error was this one:

```
nivel_obj = Nivel.objects.filter(id=nivel_id) <---
nueva_matricula = Matricula(nivel=nivel_obj, ano_lectivo=ano_lectivo, alumno=a)
```

I cannot save a new object with a nivel=queryset and not nivel=NivelObject.

it should be:

```
nivel_obj = Nivel.objects.get(id=nivel_id)
```

My mistake.

BUT, WHY ON EARTH would django give me a UnicodeDecodeError?!!

Comment: Generally it all looks correct to me. You should use Unicode literals for your `verbose_name` attributes on `Matricula`, eg `verbose_name = u'matrícula'`, but I don't see why that would create the exception you're seeing. `UnicodeDecodeError` comes from trying to mix encoded strings and Unicode objects when the encoded string contains non-ascii characters, eg `'matr\xc3\xadcula' + u'matrícula'`, so something somewhere is getting an encoded version of the name. Django doesn't do that on its own - I or other readers might be able to help spot it if you can show your view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` isn't doing what you want it to here:

```
nivel_obj = Nivel.objects.filter(id=nivel_id)
```

`filter` returns a queryset, not a single object. You can't use it as the value of the `ForeignKey` field. I don't yet see why that would raise the exception you're reporting, maybe something not stringifying correctly while it's trying to report the exception?

Normally you'd use `get` to get a single object rather than a queryset, or in a view sometimes the `get_object_or_404` shortcut. But you don't need to do that just to set a foreign key relationship - you can instantiate directly with the ID value:

```
nueva_matricula = Matricula(nivel_id=nivel_id, ano_lectivo=ano_lectivo, alumno=a)
nueva_matricula.save()
```

If your error persists, I would focus on checking the return type of `self.nombre`. Django `CharField`s should always return a Unicode object, but if you've got something really nonstandard happening and you're getting an encoded bytestring as `nombre`, your `__unicode__` method will throw the `UnicodeDecodeError` shown. But that shouldn't be possible with standard Django.

Comment: you're right, I was writing that last edit the moment you answered. I'll accept this answer, but the question of why the UnicodeDecodeError is still there. Thnx.

Comment: Probably it was trying to form an exception message somewhere to report the problem, and something is either returning an encoded string from the `__unicode__` method or is throwing the exception in `__unicode__`. A full strack trace might help debug it - or some messing around with similar queries in an interactive shell or pdb.

Answer (score 1):

The `UnicodeDecodeError` could be a really hard headache. Could be a lot of reasons.

You could try with some of this:

---

If you are using `MySQL` as database, you could use a command line like this to create it:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

See [more](https://www.euperia.com/development/mysql-create-database-with-utf8-character-set-syntax/1064) here.

---

When you create the Nivel object with the `nombre` value 'Octavo de Básica', you could try something like this:

```
nivel_obj = Nivel(
    nombre=unicode('Octavo de Básica', 'utf-8'),
    ...
)
```

Read [more](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) here.

---

You could also try the `encode` Python function. [here a tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_encode.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your links man. I can't accept it cause I'm using PSQL.

Comment: Be sure you are creating a database with utf-8 compatibility.